# Limit of a sequence of infinities

Tags: limits, infinity

I'm having trouble dealing with limits involving infinities. Suppose I have sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $a_n = \infty$ for all $n$. Then is the following true?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$$

By definition, I would have to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n - \infty| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$, but this is clearly not true since $\infty - \infty$ is not defined. If not, what's the limit then?

Comment: What does $a_n=\infty$ mean?

Comment: $a_n$ is an element of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty, -\infty\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix up between a couple of things. A sequence can have a limit. We say that $a_n$ converges to some limit $L$ and we write it $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$. If the sequence does not converge to a finite limit $L$ it can converge to infinity (some will say it diverges) and we write it like so: $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$. The formal definition for this kind of limit is as follow:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ if for every $M\in R$ there exist $N$ such that for all $n>N \implies a_n>M$

However, elements of a sequence can not be $\infty$ because infinity is not a number, but rather a concept.

Comment: Then can a function be evaluated to be $\infty$? For example, $f(2) = \infty$, does that make sense?

Comment: No. Again, because infinity is not a number. The _limit_ of $f(2)$ can be infinity. Take for example $a_n=n$. Non of the elements in this sequence is infinity (it cant be), but the sequence grows to infinity, i.e it's limit is infinity.

Comment: but measures are functions and measures can be $\infty$. For example, the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$.